# importing and sorting a textfile in python

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a textfile looking like this:

```
2013-03-10   Maxi Ica Storm Lindh -805,42  3 326,22 
2013-03-07   Hemk P Matgl Dje -86,80  4 131,64 
2013-03-06   Hemk P Sthlm City -238,30  4 218,44 
2013-03-04   Hemk P Matgl Dje -150,91  4 456,74 
2013-03-02   Lidl 257 / Sthlm Sveav -174,00  4 607,65
```

I want to import this file into python to a list were all the lines are stored and the lines are devided like this:

```
2013-03-10  | Maxi Ica Storm Lindh | -805,42 | 3 326,22
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are there tabs in that file, or are there only spaces?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: use `split()`. However, each column has to be separated by a common separator that is not present in the column itself. It seems that you are using the spacebar character in your columns (e.g. the name) AND also using it to separate the fields. You should use a tab character for column separation, or something else.

Comment: @Terry: Nope, `split()` will split this in too many columns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wasn't done with typing :P

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a tab-delimited file. Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read that:

```
import csv

with open('somefilename.csv', 'rb') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='\t'):
        print ' | '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot / will not update the source files, you probably cannot get around using a regex to parse the lines. For the input you've given, this would work (assuming 'lines' holds your lines):

```
>>> import re
>>> matcher = re.compile(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}.\d{2})\s+(.+) (-?[\d ]+,\d{2})\s+(-?[\d, ]+)$')
>>> formatted_lines = ["|".join(m.groups()) for m in [matcher.match(line) for line in lines]]
>>> for line in formatted_lines:
...     print(line)
...
2013-03-10|Maxi Ica Storm Lindh|-805,42|3 326,22
2013-03-07|Hemk P Matgl Dje|-86,80|4 131,64
2013-03-06|Hemk P Sthlm City|-238,30|4 218,44
2013-03-04|Hemk P Matgl Dje|-150,91|4 456,74
2013-03-02|Lidl 257 / Sthlm Sveav|-174,00|4 607,65
```